# iOS SQLite Blob data is saving NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, blob, nsdata

I am trying to  insert a BLOB data of SignatureView using this code but when i actually browse the database there is null instead of data. 
My signature table schema is given below.

> create table sign(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, image blob,invoiceid integer);

```
-(void)storeImageData:(NSData *)imageData withInvoiceID:(NSInteger)invoiceID{

    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite3"];
    const char *dbpath = [dbPath UTF8String];
    sqlite3 *contactDB;

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    NSLog(@"%@",dbPath);
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        int invoiceIDINT = (int)invoiceID;
    //
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO sign (image,invoiceid) VALUES (?,%d)", invoiceIDINT];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 2, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_step(statement);

        } else {
            const char *Error = sqlite3_errmsg(database);
            NSString *error = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:Error];
            UIAlertView *view = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error2" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last inserted ID: %@",error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [view show];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Always check the result of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. If it fails, log the problem using `sqlite3_errmsg`.
2. Only call `sqlite3_finalize` if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeds.
3. You get `NULL` for the blob because your call to `sqlite3_bind_blob` is passing the wrong column index. It should be `1`, not `2` since your want to bind to the first `?` in your `INSERT` statement.
4. Why the inconsistency? Why do you use `stringWithFormat` to set the value for the `invoiceid` column and then use `sqlite_bind_xxx` for the `image` column? You should bind both. Never use `stringWithFormat` to build a query.
5. You call `sqlite3_step` twice. Only call it once and bind your values before you call it.
6. You appear to be writing to a database inside your app's resource bundle. You can't do that on a real device. It works in the simulator but not on real iOS devices. You need to put your database file in the Documents folder.

Given all of the above, your code should be something like this:

```
-(void)storeImageData:(NSData *)imageData withInvoiceID:(NSInteger)invoiceID{
    // This is wrong - you need to update this to use the Documents folder
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite3"];
    const char *dbpath = [dbPath UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"%@",dbPath);

    sqlite3 *contactDB;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO sign (image, invoiceid) VALUES (?, ?)";

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, (int)invoiceID);

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                // Row inserted successfully
            } else {
                const char *Error = sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB);
                NSString *error = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:Error];
                UIAlertView *view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error2" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last inserted ID: %@",error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [view show];
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unable to prepare statement %s: %s", insert_stmt, sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
        }

        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open database at path %@: %s", dbPath, sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
    }
}
```

Comment: `sqlite3_finalize()` is allowed to be called on a NULL statement.

Comment: @CL. But why? You only need to close an open database. You only need to finalize a prepared statement.

Comment: There might be situations where calling `sqlite3_finalize` unconditionally is easier.

Comment: Thank you sir its working exactly the same as i want.