# Save and retrieve AttributedString to SQLite3

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, save, blob, nsattributedstring

I have a project in Objective-c in which I am trying to find a way of saving the attributedText from a UITextView to a SQLite3 table.
My Project Target OS is 12.1.
I am using an object called "MMItem" with a NSData property called "notesAttributed".
In my viewController Class I am using NSKeyedArchiver to encode the AttributedText into a NSdata format then copying to the object property.

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.itemNotes.attributedText requiringSecureCoding:YES error:Nil];
self.item.notesAttributed = data;
```

I then call a method in my model to save the object

```
NSString *resultStr = [self.meetingModel saveAttributedItemNote:item];
```

In the model I'm attempting to save the attributed string to a field in the Item table setup as type 'blob'

```
- (NSString *)saveAttributedItemNote:(MMItem *)item{
NSString *errorMessage;
NSString *sql;
NSInteger result = 0;

if (item) {
    //create blob encoded data for Attributed notes
    NSInteger itemID = item.itemID;
    
    sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"UPDATE Item set noteAttributed = %@ WHERE itemID = %ld",item.notesAttributed, (long)itemID];
    
    char *err;
    // open DB and save
    if ([self openDB]){
        //NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        result = sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    
    if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        errorMessage = @"Error";
    }
    else
    {
        //NSLog(@"Table updated");
        errorMessage  = @"OK";
        [self saveAttributedItemNote:item];
    }
    
}
item = nil;
return errorMessage;
```

}

The SQL Execute statement fails with error 1.

I suspect I'm meant to insert the blob into the table using 'binding' and not an Execute statement but I just find how to put this all together using Objective-c.
Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Where does a guy named 'MMItem' come from?

Comment: And what business does SQLite have with `NSKeyedArchiver`?

Comment: openDB?  Where does it come from?

Comment: MMItem is the NSobject that holds all the properties for an 'Item' such as itemID, topicID, itemDescription etc

Comment: openDB is a method in my model to open the SQLite DB

Comment: NSKeyedArchiver I understand to be needed to encode objects that have multiple attributes so they can be stored as a single item.  But I totally out of my depth here in knowing how to put this together

Comment: What happens if you try the following?  NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: item.notesAttributed];

Comment: Well, sorry, it's not a bad idea to use `NSKeyedArchiver` to make an `NSData` object out of `NSAttributedString` object.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but it still crashes with the Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Also I get a warning that 'archivedDataWithRootObject:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 - Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead

Comment: I don't write code in Objective-C any more.  According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580240/ios-12-0-alternative-to-using-deprecated-archiverootobjecttofile , it should be NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:item.notesAttributed requiringSecureCoding:NO error:&error];  Or choose any of the solutions there.

Comment: I resolved the Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue.  I changed the Object property item.notesAttributed from being an attributedString to be NSData and moved the line "NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:item.notesAttributed requiringSecureCoding:YES error:Nil];"  from the model to the viewController and it now doesn't have the thread error, however the SQL statement still errors.  I'll amend the question above to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 0):

With acknowledgement to the following post [iOS SQLite Blob data is saving NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783244/ios-sqlite-blob-data-is-saving-null)
I managed to get a working solution. It's apparent that to save a blob into an SQLite you must use a Prepare statement with a sqlite3_bind_blob to insert the blob parameters into the statement, then to use sqlite3_step to deploy it.
This then allows the bytes and length parameters to also be passed into the statement, which I don't think can be done using the execute method I was originally trying.
Here is the code that works perfectly.

```
- (NSString *)saveAttributedItemNote:(MMItem *)item{
NSString *errorMessage;

if (item) {
    //create blob encoded data for Attributed notes
    int itemID = (int)item.itemID;
    
    if ([self openDB]) {
        
        const char *insert_stmt = "UPDATE Item set notesAttributed = ? WHERE itemID = ?";
        
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, item.notesAttributed.bytes, (int)item.notesAttributed.length, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, itemID);
            
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                errorMessage  = @"OK";
                //update successfull
            }else{
                const char *err = sqlite3_errmsg(db);
                NSString *error = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:err];
                NSLog(@"Update error ID:%@",error);
                errorMessage = @"Error";
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }else{
            errorMessage = @"Error";
            NSLog(@"Unable to prepare stsement %s: %s",insert_stmt, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }

}
item = nil;
return errorMessage;
```

}

The following code then shows how the field was retrieved from sqlite. Column 11 is the blob.

```
if (sqlite3_prepare(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //NSLog(@"SQL Select OK");
        
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            MMItem *item = [[MMItem alloc]init];
            item.itemID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            item.topicID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
            item.sequenceID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);
            char *description = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
            if(description) item.itemDescription = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:description];
            char *notes = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
            if(notes) item.notes = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:notes];
            char *actionBy = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5);
            if(actionBy) item.actionBy = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:actionBy];
            char *requiredBy = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6);
            if (requiredBy) item.requiredBy = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:requiredBy];
            item.completed = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 7);
            char *proposedBy = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8);
            if (proposedBy) item.proposedBy = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:proposedBy];
            char *secondedBy = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 9);
            if (secondedBy) item.secondedBy = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:secondedBy];
            item.carried = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 10);
            NSData *attributedTextData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement,11) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 11)];
            item.notesAttributed = attributedTextData;
            
            
            [items addObject:item];
            item = nil;
        }
    }
```

Then in the ViewController, the following was used to take the NSData property and decode this for the UITextView (self.itemNotes)

```
self.itemNotes.attributedText = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:([NSAttributedString class]) fromData:self.item.notesAttributed error:&error];
```

Weird how just posting the question lead me to finding the right solution.  Thanks to El Tomato for your help bud.